# Symfony production routing issue

Tags: php, symfony, routes, virtualhost, symfony-2.3

I have configured my virtual host (apache2) in this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/web
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/web>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride All
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And i can see homepage and assets but not other routes.

if i change document root to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/web/app.php
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/web/app.php>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride All
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now i can see all routes but not assets...

How can i setup the virtual host to see all routes and assets?

Comment: this gonfig  is on windows ?

Comment: Is on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What happens when you try to access other routes using first config?

Comment: The requested URL /azienda was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName test.io
   DocumentRoot "your_project_path/web"
   RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://test.io/app.php$1 [R,L]
   <Directory "your_project_path/web">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
      RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
      RewriteRule ^(.*) /app.php [NC,L]
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

also check **web/.htaccess**

```
   DirectoryIndex app.php
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
          Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
         RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

         # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
         RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
         RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
         RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
         RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
         RewriteRule .? - [L]
         RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_alias.c>
              RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
              # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
         </IfModule>
   </IfModule>
```

asper document [Configuring a Web Server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

also dumps all routes into apache by using this comment **php app/console router:dump-apache**

Comment: Thanks i used the virtual host (the second one) in this tutorial: Configuring a Web Server. Now works!